# Questions about Azure resource management portal

Tags: azure, bing-api

I've recently been playing around with the Bing's image search api, however I have a concern I hope to resolve.

It is to do with the limit on the number of api requests that are allowed per month. After doing some reading it seems like if I were to exceed this limit, my Azure account would be billed depending on the number of api calls I have gone over my limit. Is it possible to set up some kind of alert through the Azure management portal that will stop the api from processing any more calls once a specific threshold has been passed?

If anyone has any experience using the Search api and can enlighten me, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Try Metrics Monitoring. Go to the service within Azure Portal, Scroll Down to **Monitoring** -> **Metrics** and then click **Add Metric Alert**.

You can create an alert based on the number of successful calls or total calls and the alert can notify you via e-mail. Additionally, if you want to take action automatically after reaching the threshold, you can use Webhooks to make a call out to a web application or Azure Automation Runbook to automatically run PowerShell scripts or some code to prevent overuse. You can also use Logic Apps for that. Check the following link for further details and examples at the end of the page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-webhooks-alerts

Comment: I had a brief look into the above approaches you mentioned, but I can't seem to find a way of disabling/pausing an Azure Cognitive Service, do you know if this is even possible?

Comment: No, but you can code something in your application to stop consuming it.